# GSON - print all fields that are annotated as deserialized=true

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a **Java EE** project that is using **GSON** library (Google's library for processing of JSON objects).

In my *entity* classes I use `@Expose` annotation to control which fields are considered by GSON. I also use *serialize/deserialize* properties on that annotation to control which fields are considered when serializing  a Java object to JSON and which fields are considered when deserializing JSON objects to Java objects. For example:

```
public class Movie {

   @Expose(serialize=true, deserialize=false)
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   @Expose(serialize=true, deserialize=true)
   private String name;

   @Expose(serialize=true, deserialize=true)
   private String genre;

   @Expose(serialize=false, deserialize=true)
   private String secretID;

}
```

Here when I send the JSON object to be **deserialized** into Java object I send an object like this:

```
{
   "name": "Memento",
   "genre": "thriller",
   "secretID": "123asd"
}
```

And, when I **serialize** Java object to JSON I get something like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Memento",
   "genre": "thriller"
}
```

I have this Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(new Movie());
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

that generates this as it's output:

```
{
   "id": 0,
   "name": "",
   "genre": ""
}
```

Those are fields that are marked to be serialized. However, what if I need to print out all of the fields that are marked to be deserialized, so that I can easier create a JSON object that will be used as input when creating new Movies.

The desired output is this:

```
{
   "name": "",
   "genre": "",
   "secretID": ""
}
```

Note: I don't want to change serialize/deserialize properties on `@Expose` annotations because they are set to how my application needs to work. I just need an easy way to generate a template JSON objects that will be used as input to my application, so I don't have to type it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement more generic `ExclusionStrategy` like:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IncludeListedFields implements ExclusionStrategy {
    @NonNull
    private Set<String> fieldsToInclude;
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return ! fieldsToInclude.contains(f.getName());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

then use it like:

```
Set<String> fieldsToInclude =
        new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("name", "genre", "secretID"));        
ExclusionStrategy es = new IncludeListedFields(fieldsToInclude);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls()
                    .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(es).create();
```

Note following things:

- You should not now use the builder method `.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation`.
- By default Gson does not serialize fileds with `null` values so you need to use builder method `.serializeNulls()`. This does not generate Json with string values `""` but just `null`.
- In your example Json fields contained empty strings as values but you did not introduce default constructor `Movie()` that would initialize field values to empty strings so they remain `null`. But if you initialize them - say to empty string `""`- then they are not null & you do not need to use builder method `.serializeNulls()`.

**BUT** if you really need and want only to serialize based on `@Expose(deserialize=true)` then the `ExclusionStrategy` can be just:

```
public class PrintDeserializeTrue implements ExclusionStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        Expose annotationExpose = f.getAnnotation(Expose.class);
        if(null != annotationExpose) {
            if(annotationExpose.deserialize())
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```